# Using BindConstraint in Clutter to constrain the size of an actor

Tags: python, c, gtk, clutter

I recently discovered [constraints](http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterBindConstraint.html) in Clutter, however, I can't find information on how to constrain the size of actor by proportion. For example, I want an actor to keep to 1/2 the width of another actor, say it's parent. It seems like it can only force the width to scale 100% with the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Clutter.BindConstraint` matches the positional and/or dimensional attributes of the source actor. for fractional positioning, you can use `Clutter.AlignConstraint`, but there is no `Clutter.Constraint` class that allows you to set a fractional dimensional attribute. you can implement your own `ClutterConstraint` that does so by subclassing `Clutter.Constraint` and overriding the `Clutter.Constraint.do_update_allocation()` virtual function, which gets passed the allocation's of the actor that should be modified by the constraint. something similar to this (untested) code should work:

```
class MyConstraint (Clutter.Constraint):
    def __init__(self, source, width_fraction=1.0, height_fraction=1.0):
        Clutter.Constraint.__init__(self)
        self._source = source
        self._widthf = width_fraction
        self._heightf = height_fraction
    def do_update_allocation(self, actor, allocation):
        source_alloc = self._source.get_allocation()
        width = source_alloc.get_width() * self._widthf
        height = source_alloc.get_height() * self._heightf
        allocation.x2 = allocation.x1 + width
        allocation.y2 = allocation.y1 + height
```

this should illustrate the mechanism used by `Clutter.Constraint` to modify the allocation of an actor.